# FTX API get response

Tags: python, json, api, request

I tried to use the FTX API, but somehow I can't manage to print the response:

```
import time
import hmac
from requests import Request

ts = int(time.time() * 1000)
request = Request('GET', 'https://ftx.com/api/wallet/balances')
prepared = request.prepare()
signature_payload = f'{ts}{prepared.method}{prepared.path_url}'.encode()
signature = hmac.new('MY_API_SECRET'.encode(), signature_payload, 'sha256').hexdigest()

request.headers[f'FTXUS-KEY'] = 'MY_API_KEY'
request.headers[f'FTXUS-SIGN'] = signature
request.headers[f'FTXUS-TS'] = str(ts)

print(request)
```

The output is `<Request [GET]>`, but I want to get my wallet balances. The whole code is from FTX API documentation, except the print line.

Comment: You forgot to actually execute prepared request.

Comment: doc [Prepered Reuqest](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#prepared-requests) - you have to create `Session()` and run `session.send(prepered)`

Comment: Thank you, I updated the code, but get the following output: ```{'success': False, 'error': 'Not logged in'}```. I think the header is not included in the session.

Comment: The question is still open, does anyone have an idea how to include the header?

Answer (score 0):

```
from requests import Request, Session
s = Session()
response = s.send(prepared)
print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to rename request.headers as prepared.headers as per the documentation provided by Olvin Roght

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.